# mysql show record not in other logins group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables and I want to filter the data based on the group arrangement.

```
login

id | name     
-- | -------- 
1  | drew        
2  | john        
3  | alex         

group

id | group_name
-- | --------
1  | Scientist       
2  | Singer       
3  | Teacher       
4  | Dancer       
5  | Atty       
6  | IT       

group_member

id | group_id| login_id
-- | --------| ------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 1
3  | 1       | 2  
4  | 3       | 2 
5  | 4       | 2 
6  | 3       | 3  
7  | 4       | 3
```

example if I select login 1, if login_id 1 has same group_id with other login this group  will now show.

login_id 1 has a record of

```
group_id|group_name| login_id
--------| ------   | ------ 
   1    | Scientist| 1
   2    | Singer   | 1
```

so if I filter the group

the result will be

```
group_id|group_name| login_id
--------| ------   | ------ 
   3    | Teacher  | 2
   4    | Dancer   | 2
   3    | Teacher  | 3
   4    | Dancer   | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this if I've understood well:

```
select group_id, group_name, login_id
from group_member join groups on
group_member.group_id = groups.id
where group_id not in 
   (select group_id from group_member
    where login_id=1)
```

See the [Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aac2/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select g.id,g.group_name,m.login_id
from group_member m
join group g on m.group_id=g.id
where m.group_id not in (
select group_id
from group_member
where login_id=1)
```